# How to say "Depend on libfoo, dynamically if possible" in CMake

Tags: cmake, static-libraries, idioms, build-dependencies

In CMake, I want to express the following: "target tgt should depend on libfoo. If libfoo is available as a dynamic library, great; otherwise, tgt should depend on the static version of libfoo".

Can I do this without verbosely and explicitly using a multi-pronged function?

Comment: Only if `libfoo` provides such functionality. `find_library` prefers to find shared libraries first, but that only applies to find modules that actually use that function.

Comment: @AlexReinking: `libfoo` may or may not have a static variant; and that variant might be named `libfoo_static` too.

Comment: If you're writing a find module, it's just going to be complex. Full stop. Look at the implementation of FindZLIB.cmake for the simplest example I can think of

Comment: @AlexReinking: I'm not writing a find module, just a regular project's CMakeFiles.txt . But "there's no easy way to do it" is an answer, I guess.